# Как получить абсолютный url из JavaScript+Ajax с помощью парсинга Selenium, Python 3?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, парсер, selenium

Я пишу парсер для этого сайта - https://www.oddsportal.com

Возьмём эту страницу - https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Нужно получить список URL с этого блока
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, что эти URL, формируются через JS (и Ajax). Я не знаю, как по ним пройтись. Видно, что у них есть какие-то uid... Видимо, нужно как-о их использовать?..

Если долго расписывать метод для получения всех URL, можете написать только получение URL из "Home / Away": "2nd Half", например.

[image]
[image]

```
def init_driver():
    chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_option.add_argument("headless")
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    chrome_option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)


    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_option)
    except SessionNotCreatedException:
        print("Ошибка инициализации браузера. Скорее всего у вас не установлен браузер. Пожалуйста обратитесь к разработчику парсера")

    return driver

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def parse(driver):
    driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR")
    #Находим элемент ul с классом ul-nav
    ul_nav = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.ul-nav")
    #Находим все li внутри ul, которые содержат style = "display:block;", этот параметр отвечает за видимость объекта
    lis = ul_nav.find_elements_by_css_selector('li[style = "display: block;"]')
    #Проходим по всем найденным li

    for li in lis:
        #Кликаем
        print(li.text)
        li.click()
        #Получаем текущую ссылку, на которой находится браузер
        print(driver.current_url)

        #Вытаскиваем ссылки из подпунктов (список)
        sub_ul_nav = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.sub-menu.subactive[style = 'display: block;']")
        sub_a_more_list = sub_ul_nav.find_elements_by_css_selector('li > a')
        #Циклом for проходим по ним и записываем url
        for sub_a_more in sub_a_more_list:
            sub_a_more.click()
            print(driver.current_url)
        print('==========')

    a_list_text = []
    #Получаем ссылки
    li_more = ul_nav.find_element_by_css_selector('li.r.more')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(li_more).perform()
    a_more_list = li_more.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div > p > a')
    for a_more in a_more_list:
        text = a_more.text
        #Заносим значения text в список
        a_list_text.append(text)

    for a in a_list_text:
        #Переопределяем
        li_more = ul_nav.find_element_by_css_selector('li.r.more')
        #Наводим курсор на элемент, так как оно даже при нажатии скрывается через несколько секунд
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(li_more).perform()
        a_more_list = li_more.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div > p > a')
        for a_more in a_more_list:
            if a == a_more.text:
                a_more.click()
                # print(a_more.text)
                print(driver.current_url)

                more_sub_ul_nav = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.sub-menu.subactive[style = 'display: block;']")
                more_sub_a_more_list = more_sub_ul_nav.find_elements_by_css_selector('li > a')
                #Циклом for проходим по ним и записываем url
                # if more_sub_a_more_list:
                for more_sub_a_more in more_sub_a_more_list:
                    more_sub_a_more.click()
                    # li_more = ul_nav.find_element_by_css_selector('li.r.more')
                    #Наводим курсор на элемент, так как оно даже при нажатии    скрывается через несколько секунд
                    print(driver.current_url)
                    print('_____')
                break
```

Comment: В первую очередь вам нужно использовать webdriverwait для определения загрузки Ajax

Comment: Если вы приведете полностью код, то я вам возможно помогу

Comment: Я не вижу проблем, это ссылка /bookmaker/1xstavka/link/. Добавляем домен вашего сайта: https://www.oddsportal.com/bookmaker/1xstavka/link/, там идет переадресация уже. Или я вас не правильно понял?

Comment: нет, Вы неправильно поняли. Мне не нужна ссылка на сайт. Мне нужны ссылки на разные графы из таблиц

Comment: я в коде привёл базовый url. мне нужно получать остальные url на основе базового. например https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR#home-away;3

Comment: Т.е вам нужны элементы самой верхней таблицы, т.е где 1X2, AH, O/U и т.д?

Comment: Да, мне нужны ссылки на них... И на "дочерние" элементы желательно тоже ("Full time", "1st half" и т.д.)..

Comment: @monte-cr1st0 так ссылка одна и таже, uid скорее всего спрятаны в скрипте

Comment: ну я на скрине показал, там uid17.. как с помощью этого сформировать ссылку типа https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR#home-away;4? То есть, к базовому url прибавить #home-away;4...

Comment: @monte-cr1st0 в ответ добавил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант получить так:

```
def init_driver():
    ff = "../install/chromedriver.exe"
    chrome_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_option.add_argument("headless")
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    chrome_option.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)


    try:
        # driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=ff)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, options=chrome_option)
        # driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ff, chrome_options=chrome_option, service_args=service_args)
    except SessionNotCreatedException:
        print("Ошибка инициализации браузера. Скорее всего у вас не установлен браузер. Пожалуйста обратитесь к разработчику парсера")

    return driver

def parse(driver):
    driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR")
    #Находим элемент ul с классом ul-nav
    ul_nav = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.ul-nav")
    #Находим все li внутри ul, которые содержат style = "display:block;", этот параметр отвечает за видимость объекта
    lis = ul_nav.find_elements_by_css_selector('li[style = "display: block;"]')
    #Проходим по всем найденным li
    for li in lis:
        #Кликаем
        li.click()
        #Получаем текущую ссылку, на которой находится браузер
        print(driver.current_url)

    a_list_text = []
    #Получаем ссылки
    li_more = ul_nav.find_element_by_css_selector('li.r.more')
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(li_more).perform()
    a_more_list = li_more.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div > p > a')
    for a_more in a_more_list:
        text = a_more.text
        #Заносим значения text в список
        a_list_text.append(text)
        print("Добавляем:", text)

    for a in a_list_text:
        print(a)
        #Переопределяем
        li_more = ul_nav.find_element_by_css_selector('li.r.more')
        #Наводим курсор на элемент, так как оно даже при нажатии скрывается через несколько секунд
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(li_more).perform()
        a_more_list = li_more.find_elements_by_css_selector('div > div > p > a')
        for a_more in a_more_list:
            if a == a_more.text:
                a_more.click()
                print(driver.current_url)
                break
```

Результат:

```
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR#ah;2
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR#over-under;2
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR#dnb;2
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR#eh;2
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR#double;2
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/wolves-newcastle-utd-nNNqedbR#cs;2
```

Comment: спасибо. а есть какой-то мануал по этой теме?

Comment: а то вообще сложно понять, что и как произошло)

Comment: Вам комментарии к коду нужны?

Comment: было бы неплохо..

Comment: Добавил комментарии

Comment: а чем вебдрайвер фаерфокс не подршёл?)

Comment: Это просто участок кода, который я использую во всех проектах, если нужен Firefox, то закомментирую строки Chrome и наоборот

Comment: Не совсем понял о чем вы

Comment: при наведении на этот элемент https://imgur.com/qPbEnhp появляется выпадающий список. как я понимаю у них селектор "display: none". То есть, чтобы получить url элементов из выпадающего списка, сначала нужно указать этот блок, затем вызвать метод .hover() и потом кликать по соответствующим ссылкам?

Comment: просто дело в том, что ссылки на эти элементы есть как в главном ul (эти элементы там с тегами li, display: none), так и в элементе li (сам пункт "More bets" с классом "r more")...

Comment: вот, например, ссылка на uid 13 https://imgur.com/uEYIq9i

Comment: Ну так в чем проблема? Когда цикл будет иметь значение последнего li, вам необходимо будет найти эти a, и просто также в цикле поочередно на них нажать и так же получить текущий url

Comment: Простите за назойливость. Добился вывода первого url, после чего следует _Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document_ Я могу отредактировать Ваш код, вставив свой, чтоб Вы посмотрели, в чём проблема?(

Comment: Вставьте в ваш вопрос текущий код, отредактировав его

Comment: Добавил свой код

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89215/discussion-between-danilshik-and-m0nte-cr1st0).